# Regexp for match log4net log file

Tags: regex

I try match to named groups in log(log4net) file. Regexp work good for all groups, but on exception group i have only first line(paragraph).
How to math full exeption if it exists?

Regexp:

`^(?P<time_local>[\d\-\s\:\,\.]+)\s(?P<level>[\w]*)\s(?P<logger>[^\s]*)\s\[(?P<line>[\d]*)\]\s\-\sMESSAGE\:\s(?P<message>.*)(?P<exeption>.*)`

Log example:

```
     2020-11-28 20:03:18,462  INFO Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.LogMessage [0] - MESSAGE: Executed endpoint 'mReqProxy.Controllers.UProxyController.proxy2 (mReqProxy)' (null)
 2020-11-28 20:03:18,472 ERROR Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.LogMessage [0] - MESSAGE: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. (null)
 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at mReqProxy.Models.proxy.SendRequest(proxy2 rawrequest) in D:\All\VC\mReqProxy\Models\proxy2.cs:line 54
   at mReqProxy.Controllers.UProxyController.proxy2(proxy2 indata) in D:\All\VC\mReqProxy\Controllers\UProxyController.cs:line 29
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
2020-11-28 20:03:18,487 DEBUG Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.LogMessage [0] - MESSAGE: Connection id "0HM4JNTVF8F90" completed keep alive response. (null)
 2020-11-28 20:03:18,497  INFO Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics.LogMessage [0] - MESSAGE: Request finished in 225.906ms 500 text/plain (null)
 2020-11-28 20:03:22,782  INFO Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics.LogMessage [0] - MESSAGE: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST https://10.47.6.200:8100/api/uproxy/proxy2 application/json 496 (null)
```

Comment: Note that `.` does not match line terminators, so `(?P<exeption>.*)` can't match a multiline exception's stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the pattern a bit more specific, and optionally match the exception.

In your pattern you use `.*` and `*` for fields that seem to be present in all the lines. You can use `+` to match them at least a single time.

For the `(?P<exeption>` group you can match all following lines that do not start with a date like pattern, or in this example 4 digits `-` and a digit for a short check if that will also be ok.

**Note** that you don't have to escape `\:\,\.` in the character class and the `\-` by itself.

```
^(?P<time_local>\s*\d{4}-\d{2}[\d\s:,.-]+)\s(?P<level>[A-Z]+)\s(?P<logger>\S+)\s\[(?P<line>\d+)\]\s\-\sMESSAGE:\s(?P<message>\S.*)(?P<exeption>(?:\r?\n(?!\s*\d{4}-\d).*)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jQrWuD/1)

Comment: Thx for comments, but i can't use negative lookahead (?:! ...). Now i looking for solution without neg. lookahead.

Comment: @MihalBy What is the tool or language? Perhaps like this https://regex101.com/r/7Md3iO/1

Comment: Language is go or perl. I try parse logs on promtail from loki. You answer helpfully. Thank you very much you saved my night)

Comment: Perl supports lookarounds, go does not.